# Need Help writing an undo/redo function for text editor program

Tags: c++

I have written a text editor program in C++ that has simple commands: LEFT, RIGHT, HOME, END, BACKSPACE, DELETE, INSERT, and now I need to perform the UNDO and REDO functions. In my program the user must be able to undo no more than the last ten commands.   I would like to use a vector implementation to accomplish this, but I have no idea how to set this up.  I'm not sure how to store the cursor position and the character into a vector. Can someone offer some help?

```
#ifndef CURSOR_H

#define CURSOR_H



#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

template <class Object>
class Cursor;
// Incomplete Declaration

template <class Object>
class CNode
{
        public:

                CNode( const Object & theElement = Object( ), CNode * n = NULL ) : element( theElement ), next( n ) { }
                Object  element;
                CNode *next;
                friend class Cursor<Object>;
};

template <class Object>
class Cursor
{
 public:
  Cursor( );
  bool isEmpty( ) const;
  void makeEmpty( );
  void left ( );
  void right ( );
  void del ( ); //This is the delete operation. I named it del instead of delete as delete conflicts with a C++ keyword.
  void back ( );
  void insert( const Object & x );
  void home ( );
  void end ( );
  void undo ( );


 private:

  void printText ( ) ;

  CNode<Object> *header;
  CNode<Object> *cursorPosition;

};
//#include "Cursor.cpp"
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a `deque` so that you can add and remove from the front or the back; when adding a command, add it to the back, when undoing remove it from the back, and when you reach 11 commands remove one from the front.

Comment: A ring buffer would permit the same actions, with no need for any allocation/deallocation.

Comment: @Ben, very true. But a ring buffer isn't part of the standard, and I detected a desire to stick with the standard containers; maybe I was wrong. Boost provides one: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html

Comment: "detect a desire to stick with the standard containers": CNode<> is strong evidence to the contrary, although vector<> was mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [Memento Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) and also in [GOF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

It exists for this very specific requirement. You may have to use it in combination with other Design patterns (e.g. Command, Iterator, FlyWeight etc)

> **Memento Intent**
>
> Without violating encapsulation,
>   capture and externalize an object's
>   internal state so that the object can
>   be restored to this state later.
>
> **Command Intent**
>
> Encapsulate a request
>   as an object, thereby letting you
>   parameterize clients with different
>   requests, queue or log requests, and
>   support undoable operations.

Answer (score 1):

Some other things to consider:

In general, you do not want to apply undo/redo to cursor movements (i.e. they would have no affect on the limit of ten commands limit).  When undoing/redoing a deletion or insertion of text, of course you have to place the cursor in the proper place before performing the operation. If the user is typing a number of characters without performing any cursor movements or corrections (backspace), generally these are treated as a single unit when applying undo/redo.

Comment: +1: makes me feel silly for spending so much time/space explaining many of the same issues...

Comment: They need AI on this site that recognizes when someone else is typing the same answer as you are and suggests joint authorship  :)

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on including undo/redo.  It's a great feature in any sort of editor.  It can get tricky, still.  Here are some thoughts for you (all hand-waving, no code).

I recommend learning about the [Command Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).  What you want to do is design a 'Command' class, an instance of which can "Do" a single command (like insert the letter 'A'), as well as "Undo" itself.

When the user invokes some command (like to add the letter 'A') you 'new' a Command, define its "Do" to insert 'A', also define its "Undo" to remove A, then add it to the top of your undo list, and then "Do" it.

Don't limit your undos to only 10.  Why not make it infinite?

Whatever structure you use to make a list of undoable Commands, the usual behavior is that if you have undo'd to some level, and then begin to edit at that point, then all the redos above the current level should be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

For each operation you want to be able to undo (i.e. presumably insert, backspace and del, but not the cursor movements), we can list the "undo" procedure:

- insert -> position the cursor at that character and issue a del
- del -> position the cursor at the following character and issue an insert
- backspace -> position the cursor at the following character and issue an insert

Unfortunately, your cursors use pointers, and when you undo a delete/backspace the newly allocated CNode may not be at the same address as previously, which could invalidate an earlier undo step trying to use that pointer address.  Options include:

- some additional data structures to track which pointers have been invalidated in this way, and repopulate them with new values if the corresponding elements are recreated (painful)
- find a more deterministic way to find the correct index in the CNode list

  - an absolute index into the document (but that may be difficult to calculate and slow to move to)
  - save your cursor movement in your undo history

    - mixing 10 substantive edits (del, backspace, insert) with an arbitrary number of interspersed cursor movements requires a dynamically sized container, and you'd be carrying quite a bit of "verbose baggage"
    - you could hang a dynamic list of cursor movements off each element in a fixed-sized list of each substantive edit (not much better though)

(As is, your Cnode list doesn't appear double-linked, so I don't see how you can move left without a very painful reiteration through the "document" from the header element...?)

After sorting out this indexing/cursor-movement issue, you must decide between:

- after each operation, use a deque to save the undo information:

  struct History
  {
      an indicator of which operation to undo (e.g. enum Op { left, right, insert, del... })
      only for insert operations: an object value
  }

  then have some on-undo processing function that reads these History records and coordinates the operations they describe, or
- when an operation is performed, push a *function object* onto your deque that encodes the undo and redo operations (in terms of calls to the Cursor object methods), so that actually doing an undo or redo operation just involves executing that object (i.e. the undo/redo operation is a "black box" parcelled up at edit time) / this is more elegant and flexible, but probably less familiar to beginning/intermediate programmers so may be harder to get right.  The boost library has good supporting functions for this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others about capturing undoable commands as the "do" command is executed.

I'd also suggest working through the list periodically and combining undo commands.

For example, if your undo commands are:

**Delete A, Delete B, Delete C, Left-Cursor, Left-Cursor, Right-Cursor, Left-Cursor.**

Convert that to merely,

**Delete "ABC", Left-Cursor(2).**

That way, when the user does undo actions, they don't see every single keystroke hit.  Instead, the undo happens in logical groups.