# How are text editors generally implemented?

Tags: user-interface, language-agnostic, string, text-editor

This question is probably going to make me sound pretty clueless. That's because I am.

I'm just thinking, if I were hypothetically interested in designing my own text editor GUI control, widget, or whatever you want to call it (which I'm not), how would I even do it?

The temptation to a novice such as myself would be to store the content of the text editor in the form of a string, which seems quite costly (not that I'm too familiar with how string implementations differ between one language/platform and the next; but I know that in .NET, for example, they're immutable, so frequent manipulation such as what you'd need to support in a text editor would be magnificently wasteful, constructing one string instance after another in very rapid succession).

Presumably some mutable data structure containing text is used instead; but figuring out what this structure might look like strikes me as a bit of a challenge. Random access would be good (I would *think*, anyway—after all, don't you want the user to be able to jump around to anywhere in the text?), but then I wonder about the cost of, say, navigating to somewhere in the middle of a huge document and starting to type immediately. Again, the novice approach (say you store the text as a resizeable array of characters) would lead to very poor performance, I'm thinking, as with every character typed by the user there would be a huge amount of data to "shift" over.

So if I had to make a guess, I'd suppose that text editors employ some sort of structure that breaks the text down into smaller pieces (lines, maybe?), which individually comprise character arrays with random access, and which are themselves randomly accessible as discrete chunks. Even *that* seems like it must be a rather monstrous oversimplification, though, if it is even remotely close to begin with.

Of course I also realize that there may not *be* a "standard" way that text editors are implemented; maybe it varies dramatically from one editor to another. But I figured, since it's clearly a problem that's been tackled many, many times, perhaps a relatively common approach has surfaced over the years.

Anyway, I'm just interested to know if anyone out there has some knowledge on this topic. Like I said, I'm definitely not looking to write my own text editor; I'm just curious.

Comment: Though it's undoubtedly a huge undertaking, why not look at the source for vim?  http://www.vim.org/sources.php

Comment: I get the impression you're a C# guy like myself, and I too investigated this a little bit. One thing to note is that for heavy-duty text editing, the TextBox and RichTextBox controls that Winforms comes with aren't very good.  If you dig into their implementation, the deepest parts are just wrappers around a little bit of the Windows API native methods.  You'd be much better off using some other GUI toolkit (not sure about WPF) or wrapping the native methods yourself.

Comment: I think Piece Table is a data structure used for text editors, not sure though :)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520022/how-to-write-a-text-editor-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860423/need-help-writing-an-undo-redo-function-for-text-editor-program and there are others, though this is a hard topic to search because of all the requests for editors to frobnicate something somehow on some platform...

Answer (score 46):

One technique that's common (especially in older editors) is called a split buffer. Basically, you "break" the text into everything before the cursor and everything after the cursor. Everything before goes at the beginning of the buffer. Everything after goes at the end of the buffer.

When the user types in text, it goes into the empty space in between without moving any data. When the user moves the cursor, you move the appropriate amount of text from one side of the "break" to the other. Typically there's a lot of moving around a single area, so you're usually only moving small amounts of text at a time. The biggest exception is if you have a "go to line xxx" kind of capability.

Charles Crowley has written a much more complete [discussion of the topic](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~crowley/papers/sds/sds.html). You might also want to look at [The Craft of Text Editing](http://www.finseth.com/craft/index.html), which covers split buffers (and other possibilities) in much greater depth.

Comment: No question on this topic should be without a link to Crowley's book.

Comment: Took me a second to get what you're saying (so there's basically a sizable gap between the ends of a big block, and when you insert text it goes in the middle, to be pushed to one side or the other depending on where you click next). That's pretty clever! It does seem like a pretty significant limitation that this design relies on you not going back and forth between faraway points in the text (and inserting), though, doesn't it? Then again, I suppose if it covers the use case that's considerably more common, that's definitely a strength.

Comment: There's [another in-depth guide](https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/index.html) (an "instruction booklet") that covers implementing a simple, but real text editor (`kilo`) with syntax highlighting and search "in 184 steps". I've not finished reading it, but it is well written, including its C example code. It has a lot of useful information about getting the terminal to play nice too.

Answer (score 3):

A while back, I wrote my own text editor in Tcl (actually, I stole the code from somewhere and extended it beyond recognition, ah the wonders of open source).

As you mentioned, doing string operations on very, very large strings can be expensive. So the editor splits the text into smaller strings at each newline ("\n" or "\r" or "\r\n"). So all I'm left with is editing small strings at line level and doing list operations when moving between lines.

The other advantage of this is that it is a simple and natural concept to work with. My mind already considers each line of text to be separate reinforced by years of programming where newlines are stylistically or syntactically significant.

It also helps that the use case for my text editor is as a programmers editor. For example, I implemented syntax hilighting but not word/line wrap. So in my case there is a 1:1 map between newlines in text and the lines drawn on screen.

In case you want to have a look, here's the source code for my editor: http://wiki.tcl.tk/16056

It's not a toy BTW. I use it daily as my standard console text editor unless the file is too large to fit in RAM (Seriously, what text file is? Even novels, which are typically 4 to 5 MB, fit in RAM. I've only seen log files grow to hundreds of MB).

Comment: Nice.  I will say, I run into many situations where text files do not fit in ram appropriately.  Rinex files, csv databases, and more come to mind.  It happens quite often that a customer sends me data that force me to use obscure methods of editing.  I would be interested in learning more about strategies to mitigate this.

Comment: @ChrisMauer The classic strategy for things that don't fit in RAM is to do on-disk editing. This is generally not really possible with text files but word processors like old versions of Word and Wordstar had fairly complex on-disk data structures to allow on-disk editing by just changing the values of markups in-place. This requires markups to have fixed sizes on disk (meaning they cannot be like HTML where `<b>` is 3 bytes but `<em>` is 4 bytes)

Comment: ...File edits don't cause the actual content on disk to be changed just the markup to indicate that this line or region is now obsolete and please look further into the file for the actual updated content of this line - kind of like how git works today

Comment: This is of course not an appropriate strategy for actual plain text files like csv. But you can implement a kind of scratch disk mechanism by creating a temporary file representing the edit structure - kind of like a poor-man's database. Actually, now that I think of it this is perfect use for something like SQLite - a simple serverless on-disk database

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the amount of text that needs to be in the editor at one time, a one string for the entire buffer approach would probably be fine. I think Notepad does this-- ever notice how much slower it gets to insert text in a large file?

Having one string per line in a hash table seems like a good compromise. It would make navigation to a particular line and delete/paste efficient without much complexity.

If you want to implement an undo function, you'll want a representation that allows you to go back to previous versions without storing 30 copies of the entire file for 30 changes, although again that would probably be fine if the file was sufficiently small.

Comment: I doubt a string per line approach is feasible. That is more a rendering problem than a data modelling problem. It would very cumbersome if you want more advanced features like document width formatting, font size etc.

Comment: Yeah, if there were a lot of layout and formatting requirements you would want a more sophisticated layout element than lines. It sounded like a basic plain text editor though.

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood: My own text editor uses one string per line. And by line I mean newlines ("\n" or "\r" or "\r\n") not physical lines on the screen. This takes advantage that almost all known human readable text have frequent newlines. This way, I only need to deal with small strings within a large array (or in my case, a list).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use some kind of string buffer class provided by the language. Even a simple array of char objects would do at a pinch.

Appending, replacing and seeking text are then relatively quick. Other operations are potentially more time-consuming, of course, with insertion of a sequence of characters at the start of the buffer being one of the more expensive actions.

However, this may be perfectly acceptable performance-wise for a simple use case.

If the cost of insertions and deletions is particularly significant, I'd be tempted to optimise by creating a buffer wrapper class that internally maintained a list of buffer objects. Any action (except simple replacement) that didn't occur at the tail of an existing buffer would result in the buffer concerned being split at the relevant point, so the buffer could be modified at its tail. However, the outer wrapper would maintain the same interface as a simple buffer, so that I didn't have to rewrite e.g. my search action.

Of course, this simple approach would quickly end up with an extremely fragmented buffer, and I'd consider having some kind of rule to coalesce the buffers when appropriate, or to defer splitting a buffer in the case of e.g. a single character insertion. Maybe the rule would be that I'd only ever have at most 2 internal buffers, and I'd coalesce them before creating a new one – or when something asked me for a view of the whole buffer at once. Not sure.

Point is, I'd start simple but access the mutable buffer through a carefully chosen interface, and play with the internal implementation if profiling showed me I needed to.

However, I *definitely* wouldn't start with immutable String objects!

Comment: Yeah, I agree that a simple approach like this (well, what you describe in your first few paragraphs) would probably be acceptable for small files, with the advantage of being extremely easy to implement. It almost seems to me that if you built a text editor like this, it would be your duty to make it refuse to open files above a certain size.